# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I've been banging my head against various inanimate objects for a while. I'm using jQuery to create a promotional banner rotation thing. Every 2 seconds (i'll change it to more in the future, just for testing it's short), the image and caption change.

This works fine, it rotates between them and when it gets to the last one, it goes back to the beginning. But when I click on one, and it goes back to the beginning (or I click on the first one explicitly), when it next tried to rotate it throws this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined /ftwc/:178
changeImage
rotate
```

On my two functions. I can't understand why!

Here is the script:

```
changeImage = function(num) {        
  $(".currentpromoimage").before('<div class="promoimage newpromoimage" style="background: url(\''+images[num][0]+'\') no-repeat; z-index: 1;"><div class="caption" style="color: #'+images[num][2]+'">'+images[num][1]+'</div></div>');

  $(".currentpromoimage").fadeOut(700,function(){
      $(".newpromoimage").addClass("currentpromoimage");
      $(".newpromoimage").removeClass("newpromoimage");
      $(this).remove();
  });

  $(".newpromoimage").fadeIn(700);

  $("#promoselect").children().children().css('background', '#303030');

  $("#ps_"+num).css('background', '#000000');

  currentImage = num;

};

rotate = function() {

    var imageLength = images.length-1;

    if (currentImage == imageLength) {
        changeImage("0");
    } else {
        var nextImage = currentImage+1;
        /*alert("nextImage:"+nextImage);*/  
        changeImage(nextImage);
    }

};

var selectors = "";

var preloads = '';

for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++) {
    preloads += '<img src="'+images[i][0]+'" alt="preloaded" class="preload">';

    selectors += "<li id=\"ps_"+i+"\"></li>";
 }

 $("body").prepend(preloads);

 $("#grass").after('<div id="promo"><div id="promoselect"><ul></ul></div><div class="promoimage currentpromoimage" style="background: url(\''+images[0][0]+'\') no-repeat; z-index: 1;"><div class="caption" style="color: #'+images[0][2]+'">'+images[0][1]+'</div></div></div>');

    var currentImage = 0;

    $("#promoselect").children().append(selectors);

    $("#ps_0").css('background', '#000000');

    $("#promoselect")
        .children()
        .children()
        .click(function() {
            var selector = $(this).attr("id").split("_");

            clearInterval(autoimage);

            changeImage(selector[1]);

            autoimage = setInterval(rotate,2000);   
    });

    autoimage = setInterval(rotate,2000);
```

This is all called inside the jQuery document ready function, and images is an array encoded from PHP using json_encode. I know it's messy at the moment but I just can't figure out why these functions are appearing undefined..

Thanks!

Comment: can you set up a working JS Fiddle showing the error?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `image` variable a lot, but don't define it anywhere (or wrong). Right in the first line, `images[num]` will evaluate to `undefined`, throwing an error when accessing `images[num][0]`.

Comment: I said it's an array that is encoded with PHP, and I also said that the image SUCCESSFULLY changes between them on their own, so there is no problem with the images array. (it's not included in the pasted code, it's just an array of image&caption arrays)

Comment: So where else would you get that error? "num" will be a non-existing index of your array.

Comment: num is a number passed to the function and used in the array. In the instance that it isn't working, that number is 0. There are two indexes of the array, 0, 1 and 2 (3 images to select from). It only happens when you select index 0. It then fails to rotate.

Comment: actually that number is 1 sorry, because i've manually changed it to 0, so it tries to go to the next image, 1, and fails there.

Comment: It's OK i've solved it - basically I was getting the ID of the selector clicked on which contained the index of the array it belonged to, preceded by "ps_". I was splitting at the underscore to get the number on the right: "ps_0" would return an array with "ps" and "0". For some reason, JS can parse any number as a string to an array as an index and it will work EXCEPT for 0, which it didn't. I just added  parseInt(num) at the start of the my changeImage function and all is well :) Thnaks

Comment: Hm, it should also work for the string "0".

Comment: That's what I thought but literally as soon as I added praseInt, it worked. Very strange.